# reusing modal input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I have a modal that i can submit data to, however, i need to be able to do it multiple times.

The problem i am facing is that with my current code i am only able to submit it once and then from there it will give me back my first submitted data rather than allowing me to reuse the modal dialog box.

can someone point me in the right direction as to how i can reuse/clear the data in the modal using the sample page below?

sample page here:
http://70.92.161.220/modal/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the html in a variable then after closing the fancy box place it inside `<div id="inline">`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".modalbox").fancybox({'closeBtn' : false });
    $("#newinput").submit(function() { return false; });
    $inline = $('#inline').html(); //Store the html

    $(document).on("click", "#submit", function(e){ //Make the event with document
        e.preventDefault();
        var msgval    = $("#msg").val();
        var msglen    = msgval.length;

        if( msglen < 1) {
            $("#msg").addClass("error");
        }
        else if( msglen > 0){
        $("#msg").removeClass("error");
        $("#newinput").fadeOut("fast", function(){
        $(this).before("<p><strong>Input = " + msgval + "</strong></p>");
        setTimeout(function(){
            $.fancybox.close();
            $("#inline").html($inline); //Place the html
            }, 1000);
        });
    }
        console.log($("#msg").val());
    });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".modalbox").fancybox({'closeBtn' : false });
  $("#newinput").submit(function() { return false; });
    $inline = $('#inline').html();
  
  $(document).on("click", "#submit", function(){
   var msgval    = $("#msg").val();
   var msglen    = msgval.length;
   
   if( msglen < 1) {
    $("#msg").addClass("error");
   }
   else if( msglen > 0){
            $("#msg").removeClass("error");
            $("#newinput").fadeOut("fast", function(){
            $(this).before("<p><strong>Input = " + msgval + "</strong></p>");
            setTimeout(function(){
                $.fancybox.close();
                $("#inline").html($inline);
                }, 1000);
            });
        }
   console.log($("#msg").val());
  });
 });
```

```css
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; outline: none; }
html { font-size: 62.5%; height: 101%; }

body { background: #fff; font-family: "Calibri", Arial, sans-serif; }
img { border: 0; }

a { color: #3a51b2; text-decoration: none; }
a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }

h2 { font-size: 1.8em; line-height: 1.9em; margin-bottom: 15px;  }

p { color: #656565; font-size: 1.2em; margin-bottom: 10px; }

#wrapper { width: 640px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 30px 45px; }

#inline { display: none; }

label { margin-right: 12px; margin-bottom: 9px; font-family: Georgia, serif; color: #646464; font-size: 1.2em; }

.txt { 
display: inline-block; 
color: #676767;
width: 420px; 
font-family: Arial, Tahoma, sans-serif; 
margin-bottom: 10px; 
border: 1px dotted #ccc; 
padding: 5px 9px;
font-size: 1.2em;
line-height: 1.4em;
}

.txtarea { 
display: block; 
resize: none;
color: #676767;
font-family: Arial, Tahoma, sans-serif; 
margin-bottom: 10px; 
border: 1px dotted #ccc;
padding: 5px 9px; 
font-size: 1.2em;
line-height: 1.4em;
}

.txt:focus, .txtarea:focus { border-style: solid; border-color: #bababa; color: #444; }

input.error, textarea.error { border-color: #973d3d; border-style: solid; background: #f0bebe; color: #a35959; }
input.error:focus, textarea.error:focus { border-color: #973d3d; color: #a35959; }

#send { 
color: #dee5f0;
display: block;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 5px 11px;
font-size: 1.2em;
border: solid 1px #224983;
border-radius: 5px;
background: #1e4c99; 
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#2f52b7), to(#0e3a7d)); 
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #2f52b7, #0e3a7d); 
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2f52b7, #0e3a7d);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #2f52b7, #0e3a7d);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #2f52b7, #0e3a7d);
background: linear-gradient(top, #2f52b7, #0e3a7d);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#2f52b7', endColorstr='#0e3a7d'); 
}
#send:hover {
background: #183d80; 
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#284f9d), to(#0c2b6b)); 
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #284f9d, #0c2b6b); 
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #284f9d, #0c2b6b);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #284f9d, #0c2b6b);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #284f9d, #0c2b6b);
background: linear-gradient(top, #284f9d, #0c2b6b);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#284f9d', endColorstr='#0c2b6b');
}
#send:active {
color: #8c9dc0; 
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#0e387d), to(#2f55b7)); 
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #0e387d,  #2f55b7);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0e387d, #2f55b7);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0e387d, #2f55b7);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0e387d, #2f55b7);
background: linear-gradient(top, #0e387d, #2f55b7);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#0e387d', endColorstr='#2f55b7');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div id="wrapper">
 <p>Send us feedback from the modal window.</p>

 <p><a class="modalbox" href="#inline">click to open</a></p>
</div>

<!-- hidden inline form -->
<div id="inline">
 <h2>New Input</h2>

 <form id="newinput" name="damage" action="#" method="post">
  <input type="text" id="msg" name="msg" class="txtarea">
  
  <button id="submit">OK</button>
 </form>
</div>
```

Comment: i copied in the functions you pasted above, however, it doesn't seem to be re-initializing.  Unfortunately since i'm still learning javascript, i'm not sure how to debug it

Comment: @Adam i'hv updated my code now i think it's working. Check it.

Comment: it is almost functioning -- the only thing that it is not doing at this point is showing the "your input is " after entering the second value.  as a side note, i am learning alot, so thank you!

Comment: @Adam If the answer clear your points you must accept it for future users.

Comment: if you click on the link the first time when you click OK it will say "input = [input]" however then after the first time rather than showing that second dialog, it refreshes the page.

Comment: @Adam i know that it had that issue previously. Now you have to past the whole current code again. because i'hv changed this line. $(document).on("click", "#submit", function()

Comment: please forgive my confusion, but i copied and pasted the whole code and it still is displaying that issue.  Also, i did accept the solution because it does fix the issue i was facing originally

Comment: can you please add         event.preventDefault(); after onclick submit line?  that fixes the page refresh issue i was trying to describe

Comment: @Adam sure, i have made the change.